# Printing the items in a structure

Tags: c

I want to print the elements from a structure in c, but the send and third print statements give me the warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'. I know it has to do with the pointer, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have also modified it to show the 2 structures I am using.

```
struct student_record{
int student_id;
int student_age;
char first_name;
char last_name; };


struct student_record_node{
struct student_record* record;
struct student_record_node* next;
struct student_record_node* prev; };


void printNode(struct student_record_node *node){
printf("Struct student_record_node: \n");
printf("        student first_name: %s\n", node->record->first_name);
printf("        student last_name: %s\n", node->record->last_name);
printf("        student id: %d\n", node->record->student_id);
printf("        student age: %d\n", node->record->student_age);
printf("\n");}
```

Comment: Show the structure declarations.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the pointers. The error message says that `first_name` and `last_name` are declared as `char`, not `char[some_size]` or `char*`.

Comment: You sure you get an error for the third `printf` and not the first two? BTW, the last `printf` is missing a `;` at the end

Comment: I just modified my question to show the structure declaration. also fixed the last print statement

Comment: `printf("        student first_name: %s\n", node->record->first_name);` Using `%s` for `char` is wrong.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you guys so much. I was able to get it  to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the structure declaration of student_record

char first_name;
char last_name;

indicate first_name and last_name are two characters and not character arrays(ie. strings)

When using printf("%s", ELEMENT) , %s requires the memory address of the character array ie. pointer(char *) but since you passed a character instead, it's leading to a syntax error.

To fix your code, edit your structure declaration to make it either a static array of fixed length or dynamically allocate memory to the character pointer in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student_record {
    int student_id;
    int student_age;
    char first_name;
    char last_name;
};

struct student_record_node {
    struct student_record* record;
    struct student_record_node* next;
    struct student_record_node* prev;
};

void printNode(struct student_record_node *node){
    printf("Struct student_record_node: \n");
    printf("        student first_name: %c\n", node->record->first_name);
    printf("        student last_name: %c\n", node->record->last_name);
    printf("        student id: %d\n", node->record->student_id);
    printf("        student age: %d\n", node->record->student_age);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    struct student_record_node* a = (student_record_node*)malloc(sizeof(student_record_node));
    a->record = (student_record*)malloc(sizeof(student_record));
    a->next = NULL;
    a->prev = NULL;

    a->record->first_name = 'f';
    a->record->last_name = 'l';
    a->record->student_age = 10;
    a->record->student_id = 99;
    printNode(a);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to set name as string then use `char*` instead of `char` and format specifier as `%s` instead of `%c`.